# Index out of bounds when create new thread with parameters?

Tags: c#, multithreading, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm working on my project about Bakery Algorithm but i don't have any demo of that Algorithm in C# . Because of that situation i've converted some java code that i found on Wikipedia . But Anyway , it doesn't seem to work !

**Updated** : Here's my full-working code ( old code include in "//" comment )

```
namespace BakeryAlgorithm
{
    class Program
    {
        static int threads = 10;
        static string x = "";
        static int count = 0;
        static int[] ticket = new int[threads];
        static bool[] entering = new bool[threads];

        public static void doLock(int pid)
        {

                entering[pid] = true;

            int max = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
            {
                if (ticket[i] > ticket[max]) { max = i; }
            } 

            ticket[pid] = 1+max;
            entering[pid] = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
            {
                if (i != pid)
                {
                    while (entering[i]) 
                    {
                        Thread.Yield();   
                    } 
                    while (ticket[i] != 0 && (ticket[pid] > ticket[i] ||
                              (ticket[pid] == ticket[i] && pid > i)))
                    {
                        Thread.Yield();
                    }
                }
            }
if (x == "C" || x == "c")
                    Console.WriteLine("[System] PID " + pid.ToString() + " get into critical section");   

        }

        public static void unlock(int pid)
        {
            ticket[pid] = 0;
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine("[Thread] PID " + pid.ToString() + " process completed");
        }

        public static void arrayInit()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
            {
                ticket[i] = 0;
                entering[i] = false;
            }
        }

        public static void simThread(int i)
        {
            doLock(i);
            if (x == "C" || x=="c")
            Console.WriteLine("[Thread] PID " + i.ToString() + " begin to process...");

            Random rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);
            int a = rand.Next(5,10); 
            int b = rand.Next(1,5);
            int c = rand.Next(1,4);

            double d = 0;
            string o="";

            if (c == 1)
            {
                d = a + b;
                o=" + ";
            }
            else if (c == 2)
            {
                d = a * b;
                o=" * ";
            }
            else if (c == 3)
            {
                d = a / b;
                o=" / ";
            }
            else
            {
                d = a - b;
                o=" - ";
            }

            if (x == "C" || x == "c")
                Console.WriteLine("Result of PID " +i.ToString() +" : " + a.ToString() + o + b.ToString() + "=" + d.ToString());
            unlock(i);
        }
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            arrayInit();
            string choice="C";
            while (choice == "C" || x == "c")
            {
                        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to see progress log ? (C=Yes,K=No) : ");
                        x = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (x == "")
                            x = "C";

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Bakery Algorithm in C#");
                Console.WriteLine("Number of threads : " + threads.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Progress Log");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");

                Thread[] threadArray = new Thread[threads];
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    //New code that solved my problem
                    int copy = i;
                    threadArray[i] = new Thread(() => simThread(copy));
                    //My old code that cause my problem
                    //threadArray[i] = new Thread(() => simThread(i));
                    if (x == "C" || x == "c")
                    Console.WriteLine("[System] PID " + i.ToString() + " has been created");
                    threadArray[i].Start();
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Process completed " + count.ToString() + "  threads !");
                count = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");


                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to restart the algorithm (C=Yes,K=No)");
                        choice = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (choice == "")
                            choice = "C";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, is `threads >= 10` ? Why do you use `10` hardcoded sometimes and `threads` sometimes?

Comment: Where is `entering` defined?

Comment: where is entering being populated? as in, where are you adding the values for it intially, i'm assuming it's a `bool[]` but please show your declaration and initialization of it.

Comment: @npinti: I just updated my post .

Comment: @npinti and ConnorLSW : I just updated my post again , define and plus a function to Init that array .

Comment: Please don't tag your question as `SOLVED` -- the fact that you accepted an answer does that anyway.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes : Thanks for your advice ! I'm new in-town so ... i'm really sorry about that :D.

Comment: @JKW: Also, never edit your question to fix your problem (nor even to include the fix).  This makes it much harder for future visitors to understand answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
threadArray[i] = new Thread(() => simThread(i));
```

You're capturing `i` here - the single variable which will be updated over the course of the loop, and end up with a value of `threads`.

If the thread only actually executes the body of the lambda expression *after* the loop is completed, that value will basically be inappropriate... and even if it doesn't, you could easily have multiple threads using the same value of `i`.

You basically want a separate variable for each iteration of the loop, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
{
    int copy = i;
    threadArray[i] = new Thread(() => simThread(copy));
    Console.WriteLine("[He Thong] PID " + i.ToString() + " duoc khoi tao");
    threadArray[i].Start();
}
```

That way each iteration of the loop captures a separate variable which has the value of `i` for that iteration, but which isn't then changed.

That's the smallest change between your current code and working code - but personally I'd be looking to make larger changes to use the TPL more heavily, have separate self-contained objects instead of [parallel arrays](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/) etc.

Comment: Thanks so much ! Finally , it's solved my problem . But then again another problem show up .Can you please help me again ? I'll edit my post right now .

Comment: @HuynhLePhong: You shouldn't edit your original post - if you've got a separate issue, you should write a separate question.

Comment: Oops ! Looks like i can only post a new topic in the next 90 minutes . Can you help me out ? I just updated my post .

Comment: @Huynh: No. Spend the 90 minutes making your new question as good as possible. See http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Hi Mr.Jon Skeet : I already post it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747694/duplicate-math-result-in-bakery-algorithm-c-code - But still nobody answer it ! I hope that you can help me out this time .