# Duplicate math result in Bakery Algorithm (C# code)

Tags: c#, multithreading, algorithm, math

[Index out of bounds when create new thread with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745205/index-out-of-bounds-but-its-looks-like-nothing-wrong-with-the-loop) - Continue to my previous topic , now i got a new problem with my my Bakery Algorithm code !

Here's my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BakeryAlgorithm
{
    class Program
    {
        static int threads = 10;
        static string x = "";
        static int count = 0;
        static int[] ticket = new int[threads];
        static bool[] entering = new bool[threads];

        public static void doLock(int pid)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
            {
                ticket[i] = 0;
                entering[i] = false;
            }
                entering[pid] = true;

            int max = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
            {
                if (ticket[i] > ticket[max]) { max = i; }
            } 

            ticket[pid] = 1+max;
            entering[pid] = false;


            for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
            {
                if (i != pid)
                {
                    while (entering[i]) 
                    {
                        Thread.Yield();   
                    } 
                    while (ticket[i] != 0 && (ticket[pid] > ticket[i] ||
                              (ticket[pid] == ticket[i] && pid > i)))
                    {
                        Thread.Yield();
                    }
                }
            }  
           if (x == "C" || x == "c")
Console.WriteLine("[System] PID " + pid.ToString() + " get    into critical section"); 
        }

        public static void unlock(int pid)
        {
            ticket[pid] = 0;
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine("[Thread] PID " + pid.ToString() + " complete.");
        }

        public static void arrayInit()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
            {
                ticket[i] = 0;
                entering[i] = false;
            }
        }

        public static void simThread(int i)
        {
            doLock(i);
            if (x == "C" || x=="c")
            Console.WriteLine("[Thread] PID " + i.ToString() + " begin to process...");
            //Do some thing ????
            Random rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);
            int a = rnd.Next(1,99); 
            int b = rnd.Next(1,99);
            int c = rnd.Next(1,4);

            int d = 0;
            string o="";

            if (c == 1)
            {
                d = a + b;
                o="+";
            }
            else if (c == 2)
            {
                d = a * b;
                o="*";
            }
            else if (c == 3)
            {
                d = a / b;
                o="/";
            }
            else
            {
                d = a - b;
                o="-";
            }

            if (x == "C" || x == "c")
                Console.WriteLine("Math Result : " + a.ToString() + o + b.ToString() + "=" + d.ToString());
            unlock(i);
        }
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            arrayInit();
            string choice="C";
            while (choice == "C" || x == "c")
            {
                        Console.WriteLine("Process log (C=Yes,K=No) : ");
                        x = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (x == "")
                            x = "C";

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Bakery Algorithm C#");
                Console.WriteLine("Number of threads : " + threads.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Process Log...");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");

                Thread[] threadArray = new Thread[threads];
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    int copy = i;
                    threadArray[i] = new Thread(() => simThread(copy));
                    if (x == "C" || x == "c")
                    Console.WriteLine("[System] PID " + i.ToString() + " created");
                    threadArray[i].Start();
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Complete processed " + count.ToString() + " threads !");
                count = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");


                        Console.WriteLine("You want to restart  (Yes=C or No=K)");
                        choice = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (choice == "")
                            choice = "C";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result are here :

```
2*2=4
2*2=4 << duplicated
3*2=6
4*2=8
4*6=24
4*2=8 << duplicated
```

.... and continue with duplicate values ( random position ) !

Hope somebody here can help !

Comment: move Random rnd = new Random(); out of the method

Comment: Unfortunately , it doesn't seem to work :( !

Comment: You might really want to read up on multi-threading first (a great primer being http://www.albahari.com/threading/ for example). But going through the code... `Random` will not be random enough - use a thread-local `Random` initialized with `new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())` instead for example. Your code is horribly thread-unsafe and `Thread.Yield` is quite suspect. Why are you clearing the whole `ticket` when starting each thread? And above all, why so complicated? You can write multi-threaded code a lot clearer and simpler in C#. Using Java sample of MT for C# is a bad idea.

Comment: Also, please make sure your code actually compiles and displays the symptoms you're trying to fix.

Comment: "i'll share my complete code when i finish it in 100 percent" - you don't need to have finished it 100%. All we need is a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, wihch this isn't...

Comment: @Jon Skeet : You can get original code in Java there : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm -- my code it's just a little different .

Comment: No, you shouldn't be asking readers to piece together bits of code from various places. You should present a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem you're having and *only* the problem you're having. (For example, if you take threading out here, do you still get the duplication? How do you expect anything to be unique here anyway?) Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints as I mentioned in another question...

Comment: @Luaan : I'm have re-coded it with new arrayInit() function in the last couple hours , i'm sorry that i forgot to updated my post and it take your time to realized that non-sense mistake :) ! Hope you still can help me out with that -multi-threading problem with out re-coding a whole application .

Comment: @Luaan : Please help me check my update post , i've copy all of my code with Console message in English .

Comment: So have you tried this *without* any threading?

Comment: My teacher require it with multi-threading example :( mr.@JonSkeet !

Comment: @HuynhLePhong Jon is just talking about producing the minimal sample code. If it works without the multi-threading, you will be more sure in claiming that the multi-threading causes the issue (which it likely doesn't, in this case - the `new Random` dominates *by far*).

Comment: Mr.@Mahmoud just help me out and now it working like a charm :D . Anyway , thanks everybody for your help .

Comment: @stakx : Sorry i'm new in town , i'll remember that !

Comment: @HuynhLePhong: Then *please* stop replacing the original code with the corrected code! Your question is just that: a question. You had a question about code that was not working, and the shown code should be the code you asked about. It is wrong to (partially) replace your question with its answer! I have (again) rolled back your edits.

Comment: @stakx : Okay my bad , i respect your choice ! I'll leave it to you now :)

Comment: @HuynhLePhong it's not his "choice", it's how the site works. If you replace the broken code with the correct code your question becomes useless and any answers redundant.

Comment: @Luaan : After reading your whole comment , i realized that "Thread.Sleep(20)" stuff do the trick to process multi-threading in "sequential consistency" way .

Comment: @JKW Oh, right, you're only running each method once on every thread, haha. Yeah, in that case, it again completely goes around the synchronization need, because you never have contention anywhere, even if you *did* share the `Random`. Bad multi-threaded code is chock full of these kinds of hacks - whenever you see `Thread.Sleep`/`Yield`/`Abort`/`Interrupt` in multi-threaded code, it's a good guess that it's bad code - almost always, there's a better and safer solution. Be very wary of code that doesn't work when you remove a `Thread.Sleep`. Understand the *why*, instead of copying code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a different random number for each thread ([more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx))

so try this code in your main method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     int temp = i;
     threadArray[i] = new Thread(() => simThread(temp));
     Console.WriteLine("[He Thong] PID " + i.ToString() + " duoc khoi tao");
     threadArray[i].Start();
     Thread.Sleep(20);
}
```

and the following code in you threads:

```
Random rand = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);
```

now you can ensure you produce different random number for each thread.

Comment: Wow ! Finally it's work , you can see my full code above ( included your re-coded ) . Thanks so much for your help , i'm very appriciate that !

Comment: @HuynhLePhong Of course, by doing this, you've completely bypassed the reason for using Bakery's algorithm in the first place :) You no longer have any shared resources to fight over.

Comment: @Luaan as you see Huynh Le Phong didn't use Thread.Sleep(20) so there is no wait for any task and problem is not bypassed. by the way still there is a chanse to produce repetitive results in faster processors!!!

Comment: @Luaan : "Thread.Sleep(20)" stuff doesn't seem to have any effect  :) !

Comment: @HuynhLePhong The `Thread.Sleep` would only have an effect in ensuring that the `Random` instances are spawned at least 20ms apart - which would prevent the randomness issues *if* the instances were actually reused. Since they aren't reused, it will not help at all.

Comment: Instead of the horrible hack to sleep to get different random seeds, just use a single random generator that generates the seeds for the thread's random generator.

Comment: @Voo Actually, I'm not quite sure how random that would be. I've tried it before (it's kind of an obvious solution), but I think it decreases the entropy quite a bit. I don't have enough background to actually quantify it, though. The best I've found so far is `new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())`.

Comment: @Luaan If you use a non broken random generator this will be perfectly fine. Heck random GUIDs (not sure which type is generated by default) just use a random generator themselves as part of the process (and the other parts are machine dependent so will be identical). No this should be perfectly fine as far as I can see - humans are bad judges about randomness. If you want to quantify your feelings run a chi square test or other simple statistical tests.

Comment: @Voo Okay, I've tested this with Ent (http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/) and at least for that test suite, it works well enough. So I guess the options are as follows: If you're creating `Random`s spaced far enough apart, just use the default constructor. If you want to spawn multiple independent `Random`s at one point, use a master random, and each of the others can use `new Random(master.Next())`. If you don't have any safe context for the construction (e.g. multi-threading, hidden deep inside a library etc.), use `new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())`.

Comment: @Voo Oh, and as for Guids, it doesn't depend only on the Guid version - sure, you've got pseudo-random versus MAC+timestamp based. There's still a difference between the Guid generators within a version - some are basically just `Random`, while some are crypto-random (and possibly serialized), or even based on dedicated randomness-hardware (getting quite popular on server CPUs). But yeah, the "stupidest" Guids can be very far from random. You can even have *sequential* Guids, after all...

Comment: @Luaan my point was that since all of the randomness in this use case of the GUID comes from a random generator you can just cut out the middleman. If the normal random generator isn't good enough, by all means use a cryptographically secure version. Extra advantage is that you know exactly what you'll get, but the GUID can avoid having to handle shared state yourself - that's a plus.

Comment: @Voo Yeah, definitely. The bonus I see is only in not having to handle the shared state - creating a random with new guid as a seed. Also, for whatever reason, the `Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()` approach is *faster* on my machine. And that's comparing `Random.NextBytes` to `Convert.ToBytes(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())` (on writing a 1MiB file). Probably some artifact of the benchmarking (I/O is probably the bottleneck rather than CPU), but pretty funny.

Answer (score 3):

There's many things wrong with your code, but the most important part is that you didn't read the requirements that make Lamport's bakery work:

> Lamport's bakery algorithm assumes a sequential consistency memory model.

You will be hard-pressed to find a modern computer that has sequential consistency.

So even if your implementation was correct with respect to those constraints, it would still be wrong on pretty much any computer that runs .NET. To make this work on a modern CPU and in .NET, you'll need to insert memory barriers to prevent instruction reordering and introduce cache refreshing to make sure each CPU core sees the same values... and by then you're probably better off using different synchronization primitives altogether.

Now, fixing these kinds of algorithms tends to be rather hard - multi-threading is hard on its own, doing lock-less multi-threading just pushes this to absurd territory. So let me just address some points:

1) You can't just use `new Random()` and expect statistically random numbers from that. `Random` has an internal state that's by default initialized to the current OS tick - that means that creating 10 `Random`s in a row and then doing `Next` on each of those is pretty likely to produce exactly the same "random" numbers.

One way of handling that gracefully would be to have a thread-local field:

```
ThreadLocal<Random> rnd 
  = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()));
```

Each of your threads can then safely do `rnd.Value.Next(...)` and get reliable numbers without locking.

However, since the whole point of this excercise is to allow shared access to mutable state, a solution more in line with the task would be to use a single shared `Random` field instead (created only once, before starting the threads). Since the Bakery algorithm is supposed to make sure you can safely use shared stuff in the critical section, this should be safe, if implemented correctly :)

2) To actually make the Bakery part work, you need to enforce the only proper instruction ordering.

This is *hard*. Seriously.

I'm not actually sure how to do this safely.

The best way to start is to insert an explicit memory barrier before and after each read and write of shared state. Then you can go one by one and remove those that aren't necessary. Of course, you should only need this in the `doLock` and `unlock` methods - the rest of `simThread` should be single-threaded.

For a short sample:

```
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
entering[pid] = true;
Thread.MemoryBarrier();

int max = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
{
  if (ticket[i] > ticket[max]) { max = i; }
} 

Thread.MemoryBarrier();
ticket[pid] = 1+max;
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
entering[pid] = false;
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
```

So, which one of those is it safe to remove? I have no idea. I'd have to use a lot of mental power to make sure this is safe. Heck, I'm not sure if it's safe as is - do I need to rewrite the for cycle too? Are `ticket[i]` and `ticket[max]` going to be fresh enough for the algorithm to work? I know some are *definitely* needed, but I'm not sure which can safely be left out.

I'm pretty sure this will be slower than using a simple `lock`, though. For any production code, steer clear away from code like this - "smart" code usually gets you in trouble, even if everyone in your team understands it well. It's kind of hard finding those kinds of experts, and most of those wouldn't touch lock-less code like that with a meter-long stick :)

Comment: Sadly , it's my "teacher-choice" project for me in OS class . So , how can i say no :( ?

Comment: @HuynhLePhong You don't have to say no - you just have to study why this isn't safe, and how to make it safe. Including how to handle the same job with higher-level programming is just a bonus - something that will actually be useful *to you*.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! Can you check my updated post above , i've copy all of my current code :) !

Comment: Your detailed post was amazing , it will take me time to read and understand it all :) and i'm not in a team,i'm working alone on it .

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Random rnd = new Random(Environment.TickCount / (i + 1));
```

This will give different seeds to each RNG.

Comment: Then it thrown : An unhandled exception of type 'System.DivideByZeroException' occurred in BakeryAlgorithm.exe

Additional information: Attempted to divide by zero.

Comment: @HuynhLePhong Changed to i+1

Comment: It still thrown that exception :( !